# How to Pioneer-4, "Leave the Mun in heliocentric orbit" in Kerbal Space Program?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm doing [historical missions](https://spacedock.info/mod/450/Contract%20Pack:%20Historic%20Missions), the Pioneer-4 mission.

One of the contract's requirements is "Leave the Mun in heliocentric orbit".

I've escaped the Mun in an almost perfect circle around Kerbal and still the contract is not fulfill.

Need your help, experienced space manager :-)

Answer (score 12):

"Heliocentric" means "with the Sun at its center", so you shouldn't be orbiting Kerbin, but the Sun.

Comment: Indeed, [blushing :-)]